# React-Native: i got new "Expo" app update then I found <TextInput/> is not working

Tags: react-native, expo

When I run the app along with  through expo it is showing- ***attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean abi44_0_0.com.face...***

got this error after install new "expo go" app. how can i solve this problem?

[Got this Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4Pi5.png)

Comment: here’s a workaround you can use for now: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/17372#issuecomment-1119866941

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade the expo.

With "Expo Upgrade" in the terminal.

I hope this will fix the error

Comment: This blog explain better to upgrade the expo.
https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-44-4c4b8306584a